# how to pass the query from the servlet to the google maps and getting the results back

Tags: java, rest, google-maps, servlets

User enters his query and search's for nearby places.

Can you tell me how to approach this problem to get the search and response from servlet where the user clicks search and the values are sent to google and the answer is returned back to servlet.

Thanks

Comment: Just I have a client& servlet nothing else. I want to send a query from client to servlet. My problem is to pass that query to Google. Is there any way to get google services for the same? And I have to process the results that is given by Google..

Answer (score 0):

From client you will make http call to your servlet and pass the search term. In your servlet you will the search term request parameter and will use google maps rest API to search based on that search term. You will consume the REST API response and return in your servlet response.

Have you referred to google maps documentation yet? Do you not understand the google maps documentation or you do not know how to consume rest API?

Refer to google maps APIs here and decide which information you looking for https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview

Google maps have client API as well, you could use this directly. Please check https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library#terms_and_conditions

If you want to implement your own then just google `java rest api client` and you will find tons of options. There are many libraries which you can use to consume REST APIs e.g. cxf, jersey and spring.

Google maps can be integrated directly via Javascript if you want https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: I'm not aware of 'REST API'. I'm trying to re-rank the search results from the back-end server like google or yahoo. Is it possible with REST api?. can you provide some explanation  or resources for the usage of the REST API ?                                                                                                        THANK you

Comment: Thank you, I'll go through these info.